# SharePoint OnLine Using PowerShell PNP

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am a young SharePoint OnLine user. I want Excel documents from all my sites to open directly with Excel and not Excel-OnLine. As I have a lot of sites and it would be long to make the sites one by one, I try to made a PowerShell without success :

```
$tenantName = "myTenant"
$username = "my@email.com"
$password = "myPassword"
$url = "MySharePointSiteToTest"

#  Reference au module Pnp Client 
#  En cas de problème, vérifier les chemains d'accès !
$pnpModule = Get-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell* -ListAvailable
$pnpPath = $pnpModule.ModuleBase
Add-Type -Path "C:\PSTools\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\2.15.1705.0\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\PSTools\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\2.15.1705.0\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\PSTools\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\2.15.1705.0\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\PSTools\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\2.15.1705.0\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll"

# internal params
$adminUrl = "https://$tenantName-admin.sharepoint.com"
$rootUrl = "https://$tenantName.sharepoint.com"
Write-Host *********************************
Write-Host "Admin Url : $adminUrl"
Write-Host "Root Url : $rootUrl"
Write-Host *********************************
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force 

# Admin connection
$adminCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($adminUrl) 

# SharePoint Online with PNP
$psCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $securePassword)
$spCredential = Get-Credential -Credential $psCredential


# PnP Connect
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Credentials $spCredential

#Permet d'activer la fonctionalitée de l'ID correspondant 
Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 8a4b8de2-6fd8-41e9-923c-c7c3c00f8295 -Force
```

I don't get an error. Obviously I have to forget something in the code

Comment: If what you want is for Excel files to open in the Client Excel by default instead of the Online version, you don't need Powershell. In this article (https://www.syvantis.com/blog/sharepoint-online-is-opening-my-documents-in-the-online-version-of-office-how-can-i-make-them-open-in-my-desktop-applications) you'll find instructions to set this default behavior. Take care: this site setting affects **ALL USERS**.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking to activate on all sites. The code above is just a test.

Comment: I managed to write the script, I put it on Stackexchange.
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245926/sharepoint-online-using-cmdlet-new-spwopibinding/246061#246061